# Error when connecting to pytorch docker container via ssh "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

Tags: python, docker, ssh, pytorch

I created a container with pytorch 1.8.1 image on GPU server. When I ran the container on the server computer and checked the pytorch version, it was confirmed that it was 1.8.1, but when I connected to the container through ssh connection in vscode, I could not use pytorch. how can i fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFoE4.png)

When using a docker image of pytorch 2.0 or higher, it worked normally.
All other packages including torch are not imported

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Additionally you'll want to add some more supplemental information: Dockerfile, how do you connect, how do you build. the more information, the more likely you are to receive a better answer